# MUI: div height - expand to fit content

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI to style a React app. I'm stuck on how to best set a div's height to expand with the content. In the example below, I have a Card containing a Button. When the Button is clicked, the content expands down below the Card itself.

How can I adjust it so that the Card expands to fit the content when the button is clicked? I know one issue I'm having is that I'm hard coding the Card height...

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-chaum-e61iq1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up the height of a `Card` component to `fit-content` and delete the hardcoding height from every component inside the `Card`:

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-http-mwy396?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: "100vh"` to the "Clicked" div:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-shadow-bo3cqw

Comment: Thanks, but how do you make it so that the Card starts at a height of 20vh when not clicked, but then dynamically expands to fit all the content when clicked (at a height of, let's say 50vh)?

Comment: You have your `clicked` prop, can't you use it to get that behavior? e.g. `height: clicked ? "50vh" : "20vh"`